# How to copy the first 34 fastq.gz fies into another folder, using bash, while files order is important and should be kept?

Tags: linux, bash, copy, cluster-computing, hpc

I have an Input folder (named as raw in my scratch directory, /scratch/me/raw/) that contains 544 fastq.gz files. I need to create a job_array in order to run my executable script on all of these 544 files at the same time. To this end, I need to divide these 544 files into 16 different sub-directories to be used as different arrays.

So, I created 16 sub_directories (16 folders named 1-16 in /scratch/me/array directory). However, I need to also copy every 34 fastq.gz files of raw folder into each of these sub_directories in such a way that they keep their order (for example the first 34 fastq.gz files goes into /scratch/me/array/1/ folder, and the second 34 fastq.gz files goes into /scratch/me/array/2/ folder, .... until the last 34 fastq.gz files goes into /scratch/me/array/16/ folder).

This copy of 34 files into another file based on their order in their parent file (/scratch/me/raw/) can be happen step by step and not simultaneously. Also I need to copy them and not move them.

I would highly appreciate if you coulld help me how to do this in bash? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you really want to copy them, or would generating symlinks be enough? Or move. Both these operations are quick, compared to copy.

Comment: With a quick operation, you could use a single loop through the full file list and a couple of counters could specify the target folder number.

Comment: With a slow copy operation you could do a simple loop, but build 16 copy commands as array variables, then fire those copy commands as background tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found how to do it by running: cp $( ls <insert the file name pattern here> | sed 34q ) target_directory

Comment: Using ls in this way is dangerous if your file or path names ever have spaces (or tabs/newlines) in them. You could look at `xargs` and check out the `-0` and `-z` options on `ls`, `sed`, and `xargs` which will emit and process null bytes instead of spaces as the separator. Top be honest, you could probably find a way to use xargs to split the list in batches and then specify the output folder... hmm...